# Change logo for specific contribution pages

Tags: contributions, logo

I have several contribution pages on CiviCRM and I would like to set a different logo for specific contribution pages only. Is this possible at all?
Thank you.

Comment: If you are using different financial type for specific contribution then you can set some condition against the message template which take care of it - If you need more info please let me know

Answer (score 1):

in the smarty templates you should be able to build a smarty 'if' statement with the contribution page

eg

{if $contributionPageID == 3}

or if more than one page

{if $contributionPageID == 3 OR $contributionPageID == 8}